# Detect black frames in Raw YUV video using libavcodec library in C++ NOT command line

Tags: c++, yuv, libavcodec

I have a raw YUV video stream, say example.yuv. I want to read this video frame by frame using libavcodec in C++. Once I get it frame by frame I need to detect the black frames and then convert this video into mp4.

I knwow that detection of black frames can be done using the Y, U and V components of individual pixels. So I need to get access to the individual frames using libavcodec.

Comment: What is the question? How to read a .yuv file with libavformat, or How to tell if a frame is black?

Comment: How to read a YUV file with libavformat.